# Remove arrow dropdown Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5

I'm using a bootstrap template which includes an accordion menu.
Now on one part of the page I don't need the items to open to show additional text, so I would like to remove the arrows.

I have looked around and tried several options, but have not succeeded yet.
The class that provides the arrow is the class 'accordion-button' I presume.
Does anybody have an idea how to proceed?

HTML:

```html
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">                          #1 Nettoyage à haute pression avec ou sans produit tensio-actif
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
    .accordion-flush .accordion-item .accordion-button {
      background-color: #FED005!important;
      color: #25327B ;
    }
    
    .accordion-button:link, .accordion-button:visited, .accordion-button:hover, .accordion-button:active  {
      background-color: #5500C9 !important;
      color:#FFF !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      border: hidden !important;
      border-color: #FFF !important;
      box-shadow: 0px !important;  
    }
    
    .accordion-button:focus {
      z-index: 3;
      border-color: #FFF !important;
      outline: 0;
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }
    
    .accordion-button:focus {
      border-color: none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    .accordion-button:hover, .accordion-button:active {
      color: #25327B !important;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: You marked the question with `bootstrap-4` but seem to be using Bootstrap 5 markup. What exact version of Bootstrap are you using? Could you provide a *runnable* [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see `accordion-flush` class so I assume you are using bootstrap-5.

Bootstrap 5 accordion arrow is control by the ::after pseudo element, therefore just overwirte relevant CSS attribute :

```
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after,
.accordion-button::after {
  background-image: unset !important;
}
```

```css
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after,
.accordion-button::after {
  background-image: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is tagged `bootstrap-4`. As a rule of thumb, you ***should not answer*** questions which need you to make assumptions. Instead, you should ask using a comment under the question and only add an answer once you no longer need to make assumptions.

Comment: Hi, I indeed made a mistake tagging Bootstrap-4 instaed of bootstrap-5, my appologies. I changed the tag for future people encountyering this problem. Your answer however was the one I was looking for, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 accordion arrow is control by the ::after pseudo element, therefore just overwirte relevant CSS attribute :

```css
.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after,
.accordion-button::after {
  background-image: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
        Accordion Item #3
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```